# System Drivers (Third Party)

Tags: installation, nvidia, 13.10

I have a NVIDIA graphics card and the driver that the system found works okay. I would like to download something better. How hard is it to find and install them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu 13.10 go to   System Settings->Software & Updates->Additional Drivers And it should list multiple choices. Nouveau is the open-source default. The one I selected for my nvidia was:

```
Using NVIDIA binary Xorg dirver, kernel module and VDPAU library from nvidia-319-updates (proprietary)
```

Basically to determine what you're wanting:
1. Proprietary, this means made by NVIDIA
2. Highest number available
3. Updates, from my understanding this will auto-update with the launch a new revision